# mysql row counter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table.  It has auto increment on the id.  but I regularly delete rows so the numbers are all over the place.  I need to get the last n rows out, but because of deletions, the common way of using the max of the autoincremented id column doesn't work well...

1 - Is their another way to get the bottom 50?

2 - Is their a way to get rows by actual row number? so if I have 4 rows labelled 1,2,3,4 delete row 2 then it will become 1,2,3 rather than 1,3,4?

Comment: Have you checked out `LIMIT`?

Comment: You should never need to adjust the autoincremented ids in this manner

Comment: using the max of the autoincremented id column **is not** common nor the way at all.

Comment: @Mark - The OP isn't asking to do this. They are asking to access a specific set by row index. Could be useful for pagination etc.

Comment: i think the #2 question op is trying to organize unique id.  its a pretty good question for organization i suppose

Comment: @Martin - the second question specifically asks about changing 1,3,4 (after deleting 2) to give 1,2,3

Comment: @kjy112 quite contrary , its awfully bad.

Comment: But then again, you don't need to use row numbers for pagination, you should just use the limit clause.

Comment: @col. shrapnel might be a personal issue. like OCD

Comment: @Mark - But they are talking in the context of this hypothetical row number AFAIK. similar to  `WHERE rownum <= 3` in Oracle.

Comment: @Martin - Rownum in Oracle is specific to the selected subset, not to the row in the database (that's rowid).... if I have 50 records in a table and select the first 10 PKs, then Oracle rownum values will be 1-10... if I select the last 10 PKs, then Oracle rownum values will be 1-10... same rownums for totally different records. This is not analagous to autoincrement values in a MySQL table (or to PKs in an Oracle table that are allocated from a SEQUENCE).

Comment: @Mark - I'm well aware of that. If the selected subset is the entire table however...

Comment: @Martin - even if the selected subset is the entire table (OP is talking about subsets of 50 here, which suggests it isn't every record in the table), then all it takes is a different ORDER BY or use of AGGREGATIONs and the rownum value won't match on a consistent basis

Comment: @Martin what's the point in your nitpicking? What you trying to say? And to whom?

Comment: The point in my nitpicking is that the OP is being admonished for adjusting the auto incrementing ids when my reading of the question is that is not what they were asking at all but carry on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

**EDIT**

To pick the last 50, but sort by id ASC

```
SELECT X.*
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM TABLE
          ORDER BY id DESC
          LIMIT 50
       ) X
 ORDER BY X.id
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - First get total row count like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM ...
```

then use

```
SELECT ..... LIMIT [start],[count]
```

2 - One idea is to use view , or procedure, but this is much more harder and may be used when there is no other way to avoid this

Comment: 1. ORDER BY <operation> DESC and to set 50 rows LIMIT 50

Answer (score 0):

1 - Is their another way to get the bottom 50?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY record_id DESC LIMIT 50
```

2 - Is their a way to get rows by actual row number? so if I have 4 rows labelled 1,2,3,4 delete row 2 then it will become 1,2,3 rather than 1,3,4?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes but it is ugly afaik, you do a

```
SELECT whateveryouwant FROM table ORDER BY yourprimarykey DESC LIMIT 50
```

the you fetch the rows into an array and reverse the array, in php :

```
$r = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY primarykey DESC LIMIT 50');
$set = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) $set = $row;
$set = array_reverse($set);
foreach($set as $row) {
  // display row ...
}
```

2 - You'll have to manage your primary key by yourself, its a bit risky ...

Comment: No need to do the reversal in PHP, do it in SQL

Comment: in fact, there is nothing ugly here. It WOULD be ugly if you gonna print out database contents directly from while loop. But if you're using templates (as you should), you gonna get that array anyway